# Find the indexes of a minimum value in an array, where the same indexes point to a zero in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

OPEN = np.full((10, 2), np.inf)
CLOSED = np.zeros_like(OPEN, dtype = np.int)

OPEN[0][0] = 0.0
OPEN[0][1] = 1.0
OPEN[1][0] = 1.0
CLOSED[0][0] = 1

print("OPEN:")
print(OPEN)
print("")
print("CLOSED:")
print(CLOSED)
print("-------")

# Some magic here:

# Expected output:
print("Expected Output:")
print("[1, 0] or [0, 1]")
print("-------")

# Useful function - find the minimum value in an array:
min_in_OPEN = np.unravel_index(OPEN.argmin(), OPEN.shape)
min_in_OPEN = [min_in_OPEN[0],
               min_in_OPEN[1]] # just foe better representation

print("Current Output:")
print(min_in_OPEN)
```

And this is the output of the code:

```
OPEN:
[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 1. inf]
 [inf inf]
 [inf inf]
 [inf inf]
 [inf inf]
 [inf inf]
 [inf inf]
 [inf inf]
 [inf inf]]

CLOSED:
[[1 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]]
-------
Expected Output:
[1, 0] or [0, 1]
-------
Current Output:
[0, 0]
```

As explained by the code, I need to obtain the indexes of the minimum value in the array "OPEN", where the same indexes used in the list CLOSED are pointing to "0" and not "1"

The values in the list OPEN cannot be changed to other values / data types, but the values in the CLOSED list - can. For example, the CLSOED list can look like that too:

```
[[ True False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]]
```

Comment: I think this should do it: `result = np.asarray(np.where(CLOSED!=1))[:,OPEN[CLOSED!=1].argmin()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by constraining your first array (OPEN) to the positions where the condition you want your second array (CLOSED) to be true:

```
constrained = OPEN[CLOSED!=1]
```

and then find the first position of the minimum value with `argmin()`:

```
pos = constrained.argmin()
```

The only problem with this is that `constrained` is a 1D array, which means that you need to map `pos` back to an index pair in the original `OPEN`. You can do this using `np.where()`, which returns you a tuple of index arrays where a certain condition is fulfilled:

```
valid_positions = np.where(CLOSED!=1)
```

Turning this tuple into an array and indexing it with `pos` gives you the index pair that corresponds to `pos`:

```
idx = np.asarray(valid_positions)[:,pos]
```